# How to insert column and repeat rows until the next variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, zoo

For example, I have the following dataframe (`df1`):

```
Date           Price
2020-01-01      500
2020-01-02      550
2020-01-03      480
2020-01-04      420
2020-01-07      450
2020-01-08      390
2020-01-09      430
2020-01-11      480
2020-01-12      490
2020-01-13      485
```

And I want to insert the `Price2` column in the previous data frame, so that I repeat the line until the next date, but this "next date" is not on the `df1` dataframe:

```
Date           Price2
2020-01-05       50
2020-01-10       20
2020-01-13       90
```

Would be like this:

```
Date           Price     Price2
2020-01-01      500        50
2020-01-02      550        50
2020-01-03      480        50
2020-01-04      420        50
2020-01-07      450        20
2020-01-08      390        20
2020-01-09      430        20
2020-01-11      480        90
2020-01-12      490        90
2020-01-13      485        90
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach with `tidyr::fill`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
full_join(df1,df2) %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  tidyr::fill(Price2,.direction = "up") %>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(Price))
         Date Price Price2
1  2020-01-01   500     50
2  2020-01-02   550     50
3  2020-01-03   480     50
4  2020-01-04   420     50
5  2020-01-07   450     20
6  2020-01-08   390     20
7  2020-01-09   430     20
8  2020-01-11   480     90
9  2020-01-12   490     90
10 2020-01-13   485     90
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
library(data.table)
# Create Data
#df1 with all dates
df1 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"),as.Date("2020-01-13"),by = "days"),
                  Price = c(500,550,480,420,450,390,430,480,490,485,485,490,450))
#drop dates included below:
df1<- df1[!df1$Date==c("2020-01-05","2020-01-08","2020-01-13"),] 
# Set up df2  
df2 <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2020-01-05","2020-01-08","2020-01-13")),
                  Price2 = c(50,20,90))

setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

setkey(df2, Date)[, dateMatch:=dateTarget]
df2[df1, roll='nearest']
```

Although my Price2 and Price are reversed from your expected output, I think this otherwise lines up:

```
          Date Price2 Price
 1: 2020-01-01     50   500
 2: 2020-01-02     50   550
 3: 2020-01-03     50   480
 4: 2020-01-04     50   420
 5: 2020-01-05     50   450
 6: 2020-01-06     50   390
 7: 2020-01-07     20   430
 8: 2020-01-09     20   490
 9: 2020-01-10     20   485
10: 2020-01-11     90   485
11: 2020-01-12     90   490
12: 2020-01-13     90   450
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second dataframe with `Price2` is called `df2` :

```
library(magrittr)

lapply(df2$Date,function(x){
  df2$Price2 * (df1$Date > x)
}) %>% 
do.call(what = "+")
```

It should work, let mee know if it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` + `zoo`:

```
library("dplyr")
library("zoo")

df = df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = "Date") %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(Price2 = na.locf(Price2, fromLast = T)) %>% 
  filter(Date %in% df1$Date)
```

```
> df
         Date Price Price2
1  2020-01-01   500     50
2  2020-01-02   550     50
3  2020-01-03   480     50
4  2020-01-04   420     50
5  2020-01-07   450     20
6  2020-01-08   390     20
7  2020-01-09   430     20
8  2020-01-11   480     90
9  2020-01-12   490     90
10 2020-01-13   485     90
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `cut`.

```
res <- 
  transform(df1, 
            Price2=cut(1:nrow(df1), 
                       c(0, rowSums(sapply(df1$Date, function(x) 
                         df2$Date >= x))), 
                       labels=df2$Price2))
res
#          Date Price Price2
# 1  2020-01-01   500     50
# 2  2020-01-02   550     50
# 3  2020-01-03   480     50
# 4  2020-01-04   420     50
# 5  2020-01-07   450     20
# 6  2020-01-08   390     20
# 7  2020-01-09   430     20
# 8  2020-01-11   480     90
# 9  2020-01-12   490     90
# 10 2020-01-13   485     90
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Date           Price
2020-01-01      500
2020-01-02      550
2020-01-03      480
2020-01-04      420
2020-01-07      450
2020-01-08      390
2020-01-09      430
2020-01-11      480
2020-01-12      490
2020-01-13      485", header=TRUE)
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date)

df2 <- read.table(text="Date           Price2
2020-01-05       50
2020-01-10       20
2020-01-13       90", header=TRUE)
df2$Date <- as.Date(df2$Date)
```